# How to setup pd-for-android (pure data for android) with android studio

Tags: android, git, libpd

How do i setup my project to use this git hub project; PD-for-android 
    https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android . Tutorials i found are for older  repositories. Adding it to dependencies,

```
compile 'org.puredata.android:pd-core:1.0.0-rc4'
```

as shown on
    https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android 
leads to a failed to resolve error on the gradle console for android studio

Comment: Can you paste you error info?

Comment: Error 20,13 Failed to resolve: org.puredata.pd-core:1.0

Answer (score 0):

The pd-for-android artifact should be obtained from jcenter. Check out the `build.gradle` files in the MobMuPlat Android app, which is built using the jcenter artifact:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

[github.com/monkeyswarm/MobMuPlattree/master/MobMuPlat-Android](https://github.com/monkeyswarm/MobMuPlat/tree/master/MobMuPlat-Android)